# Make UpdateView accept an encrypted pk in urls.py and return a model object for editing after decrypting the pk

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a simple working class based view inheriting UpdateView.

```
class UpdateModel(UpdateView):
    model = ModelName
    fields = ['field_1' , 'field_2' , ]
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

and the url that maps back to this view

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$' , UpdateModel.as_view() , name="update_model"),
```

Now the **issue** I'm facing is that I usually encrypt the **PK** value before sending it outside(since they are sensitive). When I receive them back, I decrypt them to get the Model Object.

Brief working of encryption process.

```
def pk_encoder(pk):
    int_pk = int(pk)
    hashids = Hashids("MySalt")
    encoded_pk = hashids.encode(pk_id)
    return encoded_pk
```

ans similarly I use hashids.decode('string') to obtain my Model Object.

But in UpdateView there is no provision for this(that I know of). In urls.py it simply accepts the **pk id** to return the relevant form for updating a model.
I understand that I have to override UpdateView or any of it's function in some way but can't figure out how. May I know how to edit this functionality of UpdateView

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple tweak. After reading the source code, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L20) , I found that I simply had to extend the functionality of

`def get_object(self)`

which is declared in **SingleObjectMixin(ContextMixin)** class.

The code looks something like,

```
class UpdateModels(UpdateView):
    #declare model, fields, template_name etc.

    def get_object(self):
        #decode and get the object in the variable desired_model_object 
        return desired_model_object
```

Hope this helps someone.